# Is there any working wifi drivers available for HP Probook 440 G2 for ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, hp, realtek-wireless

I have HP ProBook 440 G2 laptop and I installed Ubuntu 14.04 using the **3.13.0-52-generic kernel**. Google search revealed that the official wireless driver for this kernel version is not available yet. Does anybody have a working driver installed?

Right now I have a driver installed but it disconnects from WiFi randomly. Details of the driver installed:

```
description: Wireless interface
product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

Comment: "Wireless driver for 14.04"? What do you mean? Drivers depend on the kernel version, not on the Ubuntu release version. Which kernel version do you use? `uname -r`

Comment: I am fairly getting started with linux and I was not aware of it. Running the uname -r command gives the following output `3.13.0-52-generic`

Comment: In future, please use the edit button below your post to add additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a driver. But you need to compile it from source. Run these commands.

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Note: This driver should be reinstalled after each kernel update. If it is a problem for many people, I can make a dkms package and put it into a ppa.

Comment: Can you please add this ppa. It might be helpful.

Comment: I have it in a PPA, but I did not update it for some time.